# OpenGL RenderTexture - How to crop camera's view and render it to the texture?

Tags: opengl

I'll describe my problem in detail.

I'm implementing **portals** for a portal-like in OpenGL (for a  computer graphics school project).

This is my test scene viewed from above (i've put colors on the two portals so that you can distinguish them):

[image]

After a bit of research, I understood that the standard technique was to use secondary cameras linked with each portal, rendering on the portals' textures, positioned so that what's rendered on the portals corresponds to what the player should see if he was behind the other portal (using a little bit of linear algebra). I managed to do that, and this is my result :
[image: ww]

This is the view when you come out of the other portal  :
[image]

As you may see, the result is a bit distorted : the distances and dimensions are not accurate.

From what I understood, this is because I shouldn't render *ALL* the camera's view to the portal, but only the bit that corresponds to *the area occupied by the other portal in the linked camera's view*.

**My question is : What is the easiest way to do that in OpenGL?**. And optionnally in such a way that it works for any shape of portal. In Unity for instance, I know one can use UVScreenSpaceCoordinates. I'll give an example to make sure i'm clear.

Let's say my secondary camera, that is behind the red portal, rendering on the blue portal, sees this (except for the red portal itself that is normally in a non-rendered layer for this cam):
[image]

Then, **how to make it so that what is rendered on the blue portal is only this area?** (again, forget about the red portal and imagine what is behind)
[image]

This is normally possible since the projection of the red portal's surface in the secondary camera's view is the same as the projection of the blue portal's surface in the main camera's view.

Comment: You need to adjust fov of your portal-camera, render to a texture with format close to the portal-object (to stay optimal), then adjust UV textures coordinates of the portal-object to keep proper aspect-ratio once texture is mapped on. Crop = Narrowed FOV + UV Texture adjustment.

Comment: @Sedenion What should I use for the UV Texture adjustment in real time? And for the fov, should I use glFrustum? I'm not an expert in openGL.

Comment: You don't have to adjust UV in real time, simply once according object shape and texture resolution to keep proper aspect ratio. I recommend to implements your own perspective+view matrices implementation, you'll have better control. https://ogldev.org/www/tutorial12/tutorial12.html https://solarianprogrammer.com/2013/05/22/opengl-101-matrices-projection-view-model/

Comment: I don't understand how my uv coordinates can be fixed since the other portal's area won't have the same shape and position in portal camera's view according to the position and orientation of the portal camera? If I'm not mistaken, it is not even always centered in the portal camera's view?

Comment: Hem, indeed, you right. So you need to adjust the object-portal UV coordinate in real-time too... You'll probably have to implement an UV projection mechanism, from the main camera view, to be applied to the portal-object.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much  for you answer ! However I still don't know how to do that :(

Comment: Your perspective + view matrix is made to project vertices to screen (or texture), you can use the same to project vertices into an UV map, it is simply mater of coordinate (look at graphic software UV mapping tools for inspiration), then, you only need to properly apply this to your rendered texture. https://renderguide.com/blender-uv-mapping-tutorial/